# What is the best way convert a PHP associate array to a string that has only values

Tags: php, arrays

```
$columns = array(
    'Team 1' => 'baltimore',
    'Team 2' => 'michigan'
);
```

How do I convert this to a string =>

```
baltimore, michigan
```

Comment: Using [implode(', ', $columns)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker Why are you always commenting what is the actual answer ? Just asking :)

Comment: @AdamSinclair - because I believe that if it can be answered in fewer characters than the length of a tweet, then it's only worth commenting

Comment: I so the same if  its a one line answer, also with a 91k rep, i don't think he *needs* the points :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = implode(', ', $columns);
```

or

```
$string = join(', ', $columns);
```